# warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c++

How am I not returning any values within the following function?

```
bool operator<=(string a, const Zoo& z) {
// Pre: none
// Post: returns true if animal a is in Zoo z.
//       the owner does not count as an animal.

    for ( int i=0; i< z.count; i++ ) {   
        if (z.cage[i] == a){
            return true;
        }

        else {
          return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: when z.count is less than 1?

Comment: You can remove the else part and just return false outside the loop.

Comment: And that's a really bad use of operator overloading.

Comment: The warning means the compiler can't prove that control never reaches the closing `}`. Even if you happen to know that `z.cout > 0`, you'd probably still get the warning.

Comment: Besides the problem with the implementation of the operator, it seems to be operator overloading abuse to use `<=` (i.e. "less than") as an "element of" operator. It's really better to name it `.contains`, so the code which uses this function speaks for itself (e.g. `if (zoo.contains(x)) { ...` = "if zoo contains x then...")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function returns a `bool` but there's a potential code path (e.g. `z.count` is `0`) where it may reach the end of the function and return nothing. Hence, the warning issued by the compiler.

Add `return false;` (or `return true;` but `false` seems appropriate with your current logic) at the end of your function.

As pointed out by others, your `else` part is also wrong. I'd rewrite it as:

```
bool operator<=(string a, const Zoo& z) {
// Pre: none
// Post: returns true if animal a is in Zoo z.
//       the owner does not count as an animal.

  for ( int i=0; i< z.count; i++ ) {
       if (z.cage[i] == a){
          return true;
        }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally put the "not found" case as the else branch *inside of your loop body*. This means that if the first item is not the one you're looking for, you already exit the loop.

This has of course two problems: if the element you're looking for is at another position, you don't find it. Also, if `z.cage` is empty, you don't enter the loop and no value is returned, that's what the compiler tells you with the warning.

Solve the problem by removing the else branch. Only *after the loop*, `return false` since then you know that the element hasn't been found.